# Registering to OnClick event of ActiveX control

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, activex, eventhandler

Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure out how to do the following:

I am developing an Excel Add-In in VSTO / .NET / C#.

I have been able to find out how to get references to the ActiveX controls in a worksheet. It is possible via the worksheet.OLEObjects collection.

I can search that collection for a particular button if I know the name of the button. So far, so good.

But now: How can I register an event handler that gets called when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution now, there: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2009/10/02/excel-how-to-run-c-code-behind-with-a-click-of-a-button-on-a-worksheet-without-vba-code.aspx

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;
using MSForms = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;

// ...

// set name of button
var cmdButton = (Excel.Shape) ws.Shapes.Item (1);
cmdButton.Name = "btnClick";

// ...

// get button by name
var cb = (MSForms.CommandButton) NewLateBinding.LateGet (
   ws, // Worksheet object
   null, "btnClick", new object [0], null, null, null
);

// register event handler
cb.Click += click;

// ...

// event handler
void click () {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: but can't know which button clicked. do you know any workaround to get sender ?

Comment: You can register a different handler for each button. Maybe it's possible to register a lambda (didn't try): `void click (int buttonNumber) { ... } ... cb.Click += (System.Action) ( () => { click(1); } ); cb2.Click += (System.Action) ( () => { click(2); } );` etc.

Comment: It's working fine with me , thank you `label.Click += (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.LabelControlEvents_ClickEventHandler)(() => 
                        {
                            string name = labelObj.Name;
                            Label_Click(name);
                        });`

Answer (score 0):

Not likely this is still relevant for you but might be useful for someone else. I found LateGet to be quite quirky, I use this instead:

```
foreach (Worksheet sheet in excelApp.Worksheets)
{
    foreach (Shape obj in sheet.Shapes)
    {
        CommandButton xx = sheet.OLEObjects(obj.Name).Object;
        xx.Click += xxClicked;
    }
}
```